# Как на pascal записать 2pi?

Tags: pascal

Как вместо 6.28 написать 2pi?

`P:=H/6.28;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```pascal
P := H / Pi / 2
```

Если нужна документация, она [здесь](https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/system/pi.html)

Comment: А если у ТС не freepascal?

Comment: Аналогично http://pascal.net.ru/Pi